# How to pack an xib bundle inside the Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, bundle

I have working in creating a frame work, that perfectly working as expected. I need to call a xib from the frame work. So i created a xib bundle out side the framework. Is it possible to create the bundle that was included in the framework.

Answer (score 2):

No need of additional bundle to add xib in case of framework. If you are using static framework for adding resources and xib you would require a bundle.

Steps to get xib through framework:

1. Add xib in your framework project.
2. Add the xib to compile resources (build settings)
3. Build your project
4. Go to Derived data.
5. Take the **.embededFramework** instead of .framework

Now your .embededFramework contain xib in compiled form (.nib). Hope this might resolve your issue.

Comment: To make it clear are you using https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework to configure your xcode to fake framework???

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Try this [iOS-Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework). I have done my framework with jverkoey's tutorial.

Comment: i already tried... this project creating the bundle as a separate file. If possible, then combine framework and bundle as a single file

Comment: Ok, I got it. Before i built a framwork with xib from out side the framework, I have used a other way. That is combine a xib to binary code by ibtool, then create file with binary code. When you alloc init view controller in your framework, you load by code:  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"SomeNib.xib.bin"];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithData:data bundle:nil];